# Finding image based on closest camera pose

Tags: machine-learning, computer-vision, image-preprocessing

I have a camera matrix world of a 3D scene (let's call it A):

```
[[ 6.86118087e-01 -7.27490186e-01  1.11022302e-16  0.00000000e+00]
 [ 3.82193007e-01  3.60457832e-01  8.50881106e-01  0.00000000e+00]
 [-6.19007654e-01 -5.83804917e-01  5.25358300e-01  0.00000000e+00]
 [-2.89658661e+00  5.19178303e-01 -3.50478367e-02  1.00000000e+00]]
```

And, I have 1000 2D images of the scene. For each image, I have pose (camera to world) as follows:

```
[[-9.55421e-01  1.19616e-01 -2.69932e-01  2.65583e+00]
 [ 2.95248e-01  3.88339e-01 -8.72939e-01  2.98160e+00]
 [ 4.07581e-04 -9.13720e-01 -4.06343e-01  1.36865e+00]
 [ 0.00000e+00  0.00000e+00  0.00000e+00  1.00000e+00]]
```

I want to find the image that is closest to A based on their pose matrix. How do I compare A with the camera pose of each image?

What is closest?

Just a little background, we asked annotators to write descriptions of an object in a 3D scene. Along with that, we also captured camera parameters, such as matrix world (see A above), center, lookat, and dof, so that we can estimate where in 3D scene were they looking at when they wrote the description. So, now I am trying to create a training set of images (one image for each scene from 1000 available) and would like to find the image that best matches the recorded camera parameters.

Please let me know if more information is needed for clarity.

Comment: what do you mean by 'closest' ?

Comment: Image pose that is closest to A. I would think that is in terms of distance between two coordinates. Is the information (A and pose for each image) enough to calculate that? Or do we need camera center, look at, dof, etc?

Comment: Can I compare A to a camera matrix of an image and find out which two matrices are similar? That will help me find the image frame I’m looking for.